# XPath find element by position of different element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

### Example html:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="foo"></td>
            <td class="bar"></td>
            <td class="buzz"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Problem

I have row position (`//tbody/tr[X]`) and header class (`//thead//td[@class="XXX"]`)

I want to find table data cell using row and column

For example `<td>5</td>` can be located by `//tbody/tr[2]` and `//thead//td[@class="bar"]`

Pseudo-xpath:

`//tbody/tr[2]/td[position() = //thead//td[@class="bar"]::position()]`

---

I was tweaking with `ancestor::` axis but it was dead end.

Any ideas how to write it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this XPath to select required node:

```
//tbody/tr[2]/td[position() = count(//thead/tr/td[@class="bar"]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]
```

Instead of position we're checking the *count of preceding siblings + 1*